# npx create-react-app causes vulnerabilities

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, postcss, react-scripts

I recentyl tried to create a new react app with `npx create-react-app`, but the resulting app has over 80 moderate vulnerabilities. Upon further inspection, it seems that my project is using and outdated version of `postcss` different from the stable 8.3.0. Is there a way to fix these vulnerabilities? If so, I would deeply appreciate any help or hint.

For context, these are the versions of the tools I'm using:

- node: 14.17.0
- npm: 7.15.0
- npx: 7.15.0

And this is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: bump those package that you think has the vulnerabilities.

Comment: @ME-ON1 what do you mean by bump and how should I proceed?